How to adjust the width of a MDBoxLayout depending on MDLabel content
I'm trying to code put a KivyMD MDIcon and a  MDLabel inside a MDBoxLayout. I want the width of the MDBoxLayout to automatically increase or decrease as the size of the MDLabel changes. But I'm experiencing a bit of a problem with the alignment of the label's text.
Here's my KivyMD code





MDScreenManager:



    id: screen_manager



    HomeScreen:







<HomeScreen>:



    

    MDBottomNavigation:



        id: bottom_nav



        selected_color_background: "white"



        text_color_active: "lightgrey"







        MDBottomNavigationItem:



            name: "home_page"



            icon: "home"



            text: "Home"







            MDFloatLayout:



                id: container







                ScoreWidget:



                    size_hint: None, None



                    height: dp(50)



                    width: self.minimum_width



                    padding: [dp(10), dp(10), dp(10), dp(10)]



                    spacing: dp(10)



                    pos_hint: {"x": 0.6, "y": 0.8}



                    



                    canvas.before:



                        Color:



                            rgba: .2, .6, .86, 1



                        RoundedRectangle:



                            pos: self.pos



                            size: self.size



                            radius: [dp(10),]







                    MDBoxLayout:



                        orientation: "horizontal"



                        size_hint: None, None



                        size: self.minimum_size



                        padding: dp(5)



                        spacing: dp(10)







                    MDIcon:



                        id: score_icon



                        icon: "star"



                        size_hint: None, None



                        size: dp(50), dp(50)



                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5}







                    MDLabel:



                        id: score_label



                        text: "1280"



                        halign: "left"



                        size_hint: None, None



                        size: self.texture_size



                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 

0.5}








And the Python code



class HomeScreen(MDScreen):

    pass



class ScoreWidget(MDBoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(ScoreWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation = "horizontal"

        self.bind(minimum_width = self.setter("width"))

        



class Test(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        

        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"

        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

        

        return Builder.load_string(kv)

            



if __name__ == '__main__':

    Test().run()




Thank you
